# Unable to parse Command line argument in Python

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I am trying to create a script that takes command line argument and based on the input, it calls out to relevant function. 
Here is how my main function looks like:

```
from lib.updatefeed import gather
#stdlib imports
import argparse



def main():
    print "test"
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument('-ip', type=str, nargs='+', help="Search for a single IP")

    parser.add_argument('-list', type=str, nargs='?', help="Search for a list of IP")
    parser.add_argument('-update', type=str, nargs='?', help='Update the local storage')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.ip:
        if len(args.ip) > 4:
            print "Too many"
            sys.exit(1)
        parse_ip(args.ip)
    if args.list:
        parse_ipList(list)
    if args.update:
        print "updating"
        gather()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

All other Arguments are working fine and the respective functions are being called. The only problem is with the "update" argument. 
For some reason, the `gather()` function is not getting called when the -update arg is passed. I have also added a print statement before the function call but that is also not getting printed either.

Can anyone help me in identifying the root cause.

Here is a part of my gather function as well:

```
def gather(self):
    if not os.path.exists('New'):
        os.mkdir('New')
    print "Starting feed update process"
```

Comment: `gather(self)` is method in class - but you call it as normal function. Is it your real code ?

Comment: The complete code is present here: https://github.com/abhinavbom/Threat-Intelligence-Hunter/blob/master/tih.py

Comment: the gather() function is defined here: https://github.com/abhinavbom/Threat-Intelligence-Hunter/blob/master/lib/updatefeed.py

Comment: Following error without '-'. All other args are working fine and they are with '-'.  error: unrecognized arguments: -update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
parser.add_argument('-update', type=str, nargs='?', help='Update the local storage')
```

declares the option `-update` as taking a single optional argument (`nargs='?'`); the value of the option will be either the argument, if supplied, or the value of the `default` key. However, you don't provide a `default` key, and the default `default` is `None`.

So if you just provide the command-line option `-update` with no argument, then the values of `args.update` will be `None`, and the test:

```
if args.update:
        print "updating"
        gather()
```

will fail, so nothing will be done.

Apparently, you only care whether `-update` is present in the command-line, so it should not take any arguments. To handle this case, define the option as having the action `store_true`, and leave out the `type` and `nargs` parameters:

```
parser.add_argument('-update', action='store_true', help='Update the local storage')
```

Comment: Thanks alot. The detailed explanation and suggested solution solved my problem.